QGIS 3.34 Prizren Failure to Launch
I recently installed QGIS 3.34 Prizren on my Windows 64-bit system, but it fails to launch. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling it, and also attempted to use QGIS 3.38.1 Grenoble, but the issue persists.
When I launch QGIS, it freezes on the startup page, displaying "QGIS Ready!" at the bottom, but it doesn't progress any further. I have reviewed the forum as well as the technical documentation and have not been able to get QGIS to launch.
Any ideas on what might be causing this?

What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Have you tried 3.28? 3.34 seems to be still buggy on startup. Alternatively, try starting QGIS with a new user profile.

@Erik is it possible to choose a new user profile if you are unable to start QGIS at all?

The default path to the user profiles is C:\Users-yourusername-\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles. Renaming the "profiles"-folder should result in QGIS creating a new, default folder, thus enabling starting QGIS with a new, empty profile.

Thank you for the feedback. I tried creating a new user profile and optimized my PC by updating drivers, cleaning caches, etc. I also uninstalled and reinstalled the software several times. Unfortunately, I still couldn't get version 3.34 to move past the launch page. Following your suggestion, I reverted to version 3.28 and was able to continue with my work.
